# generating array of parents paths of a URL

Tags: php, arrays, path, explode

so if I have a string like this, e.g. "/path1/folder/fun/yay/"

How can I run that through a function to return an array of all the parent paths, looking like this:

```
array (
    '/',
    '/path1/',
    '/path1/folder/',
    '/path1/folder/fun/',
    '/path1/folder/fun/yay/'
)
```

This is what I have so far, obviously it doesn't work and it's confusing to say the least...

```
$a = explode('/',$path); $ii = 0; $path_array = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($a); $i++) {

    if ($a[$i]) { 

        $path_array[$ii] = "";

        for ($n = 0; $n < $i; $n++)
        {

        $path_array[$ii] .= $a[$n];

        }

        $ii++;

    }   
}

file_put_contents('text.txt',serialize($path_array));
```

Thanks!

BTW my end goal here is to be able to run an SQL query on a table of folder paths to increment a value on a folder and all of its parents.

Maybe there's some sort of SQL operator where I could select all rows whose path is a part of the path I input?  Kinda like this in reverse:

```
mysqli_query($mysqli,'UPDATE content_folders SET size = size+'.filesize("content/$id").' WHERE path LIKE "'.$path.'%"')
```

Answer (score 0):

As for the PHP function - something like this would work:

```
function returnAllPaths ( $fullPath = '/' , Array $pathHistory = array() )
{
    while ( strlen($fullPath) > 1 AND $fullPath[0] === '/' )
    {   
        array_push($pathHistory, $fullPath); 
        $fullPath = preg_replace('%(.*/)[^/]+(?:/)?$%is', '$1', $fullPath);        
    }
    array_push($pathHistory, $fullPath);
    return array_reverse($pathHistory);
}
```

Comment: what is the $returnPath argument for sir?

Comment: Sorry - I was editing some other code and completely lost it. Updated the answer with new function now :) (Thanks for the heads-up btw!)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
$path = '/path1/folder/fun/yay/';
$path = explode('/',$path);
$path = array_filter($path);
$iniVal = '';
$array_paths = array();
array_push($array_paths,'/');
foreach($path as $array){
    $value = $iniVal.'/'.$array.'/';
    array_push($array_paths,$value);
    $iniVal .= '/'.$array;
}


//print_r($array_paths);
```

Output would display in array such as :

```
Array ( [0] => / [1] => /path1/ [2] => /path1/folder/ [3] => /path1/folder/fun/ [4] => /path1/folder/fun/yay/ )
```

same as

```
array (
    '/',
    '/path1/',
    '/path1/folder/',
    '/path1/folder/fun/',
    '/path1/folder/fun/yay/'
)
```

**DEMO** : [PHP FIDDLE](http://codepad.viper-7.com/XB2nML)